# Is it better to have a huge HBase table or a few smaller one

Tags: hbase, database-schema, nosql

I'm new to **HBase** and would like to design an **HBase** table (let's say for customers).

**I have two options:**

1. either create a single table which ends up to be huge. This table is going to store information for all customers
2. divide the huge big table into multiple tables (one per customer). I'd like to know which one is a better design in terms of performance?

The single table in option 1 might have up to 100 billions records and each table in the second design may have up to 100 millions records.

Comment: So you have 100 billion customers?

Comment: no, let's say 10000 customers.

Comment: So that's different, they can easily fit in a single table

Comment: so you mean it is better to have a separate table for each customer?

Comment: Thats exactly what I didn't say

Answer (score 1):

Going by Hbase design principles

- It hardly matters one has a single table or multiple table , what matters is what is the total no of active regions hosted on a Region Server .

Lets take approach of multiple table:
1. Application logic will need to decide which table to look for the data . 
2. More no of Regions/region sever 
3. As number of region is more , more number of memstores , more flushes

Lets take approach of single Table 
* less number of regions 
* No application logic required to fetch data for any "customer"
* relatively less number of regions

Overall figure out what is the size of your Region Server Heap , and depending on that figure out how many regions can it hold , maintaining memstore size near 300Mb .

if num region/ regionserver ~30-100  one can support any number of tables but cumulative sum of all the regions across the table /Region server should be ~30-100